# Grails jasper parameters

Tags: grails, plugins, jasper-reports

I am using Jasper plugin for reports. what I need is to pass 3 parameters to the jrxml. Of those 3 parameters, two are strings and one is a list. I define the same in jrxml. In my gsp I am passing the parameters like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="monthIndex" value="${month}" />
<input type="hidden" name="yearIndex" value="${year}" />
<input type="hidden" name="orgList" value="${orgInsList}"/>
```

Here `orgInsList` is the list . When I pass the parameters like this, I am getting error like incompatible type.

Comment: Any chance you could post the actual error rather than a vague recollection of the error?

Comment: I think, that happens because you are passing String, not List

Comment: yes . I want to pass list to the jrxml.How can i do that

Answer (score 0):

Before you call the `jasperService` (instead of calling the jasper controller), preprocess the parameters. In **your** controller method use something like this:

```
params.orgList = params.orgList.tokenize(',')
def reportDef = jasperService.buildReportDefinition(params, request.getLocale(), [data: recordsList])
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Report." + reportDef.fileFormat.extension + "\"");
response.contentType = reportDef.fileFormat.mimeTyp
response.characterEncoding = "UTF-8"
response.outputStream << reportDef.contentStream.toByteArray()
```

You'll need to `def jasperService` in your controller so grails injects the dependency for you.